# poor performance with http live streaming ogv

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a `http live streaming video` with `ogv` format which should be read and presented in a web page player on desktop and tablets.
but the problem is poor performance, since it may be a very long stream like tv or long movies, anyone has any idea why it is so damn slow and with poor performance?
i tried many players but seems no one really support `http live streaming`.
ican change the streaming format or codec if needed but have no faintest idea about how to play it smooth and fast.
PS. i know i should stream form a web server and i am doing this correct. i have the stream in my VLC player very smooth and very well.
this is a picture of how it is presented in chrome in fire fox i have the same problem.
[image]

and here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Joobeen Ltd.</title>
</head>
<body>
<video src="http://192.168.3.130:8080/ghasemi" type="video/ogv">
    Your browser does not support the VIDEO tag and/or RTP streams.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML has nothing to do with this problem.  You are simply out of bandwidth.  Choose a lower bitrate, and/or choose a better codec such as H.264.

Comment: thanks, but it did not helped so much yet i have the same problem, and i ran my stream in a LAN and there should be no problem for band width

Answer (score 0):

update your graphics driver?
also change to mp4/h.264 and WebM and see how that goes for you.